# Textbook for 2nd linear algebra course

Tags: textbooks, linear-algebra

I am teaching (for the first time) a 2nd course in linear algebra. The students will have had a beginning course in linear algebra and a beginning course in abstract algebra. I am considering Hoffman and Kunze (which I had in an undergraduate course) or Curtis. Would you please tell me about your experiences with this course and/or these books or others? Thank you.

Comment: I think Insel Spence and Friedberg is an easier read. But, it's been a while since I read Hoffman and Kunze (didn't work well for me as an undergrad)

Comment: I thoroughly enjoyed Hoffman and Kunze. I'm eager to try this one: [Bruce Cooperstein - Advanced Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Linear-Algebra-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/1439829667/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1405616006&sr=8-1&keywords=bruce+cooperstein+linear+algebra).

Comment: I am eager to see it too. I just ordered it from another library in Ohio. Thank you both.

Comment: Roman's text is worth a look as well.

Comment: What material do you want to cover?

Comment: I want to cover the basics of vector spaces, linear transformations, Jordan Canonical Form, and time permitting some applications. I just picked up Cooerstein's book and I like it at first glance. It's definitely easier than HJoffman and Kunze (although I love that book).

Comment: Are you picturing a second course in linear algebra as in a two-semester linear algebra course, or more like, a return to it in upper-division with more formal proofs and the assumption they've studied things like calc 3 and foundations...?

Comment: @Angela so... which did you choose and how did it go? Maybe you can answer your question. I'd be interested in your experience. I only teach the higher linear algebra to select students and not quite in a classroom setting, so, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Rob Beezer at the University of Puget Sound has an open "[Second Course in Linear Algebra](http://linear.ups.edu/scla/html/index.html)" which, though I believe still in draft form, he has used for an advanced linear algebra course a few different places, and contains many of the topics you just mentioned.  (Well, actually the vector spaces are in the [first course](http://linear.ups.edu/fcla/index.html).)  I'm not familiar with the other texts you mention, though, so I can't compare - this is just a data point, if a very late one.

Comment: For a first-semester course, there are at least two serious contenders that are open source. Beezer has a first-semester book, and so does Hefferon. I like Hefferon's a lot, haven't looked as carefully at Beezer's.

Comment: Yes, and https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/ has a couple others I am not familiar with; you may also want to look at https://lyryx.com/products/mathematics/linear-algebra-applications/ along those lines.  That said, the OP was about a second course, which I think there are a lot fewer resources for - and what people think a "second course" is probably varies extremely widely, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sergei Treil *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* is used in a first course for honors linear algebra at Brown, so could be useful for a second course at some other places.

https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong?authuser=0